# How to add Entity to Data Source after it is initialized in TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

Initial entity is defined like below

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm"


@Entity()
export class Product {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
```

DataSource is initialised with following code

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { Cart } from "../entity/Product"

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 5432,
    username: "engineerhead",
    password: "",
    database: "test",
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false,
    entities: [ Product ],
    migrations: [],
    subscribers: [],
})

export default async () => {
    await AppDataSource.initialize();
}
```

In setup code, database is initialised

```
import initDB from "./data-source.ts"

await initDB();
```

Now I have another entity which has to be added at run time

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm"


@Entity()
export class Cart{
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number
```

I have tried to get entities' array from options object but it is read only

```
import AppDataSource from "./data-source"

const ents = AppDataSource.options.entities;
```

**How do I add cart to DataSource's entities's array at run time after it has been initialised?**

Comment: See this feature request (https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/5261) and this SO thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57459643/typeorm-dynamically-set-database-schema-for-entitymanager-or-repositories-at) for discussion on this and why it is not currently possible. Essentially, the schema cannot be re-written post-launch, so your only option is to have the Cart entity always in your schema.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you cant add data to the entities is because you only defining the id, you have to set the properties of the entities, like in this case:

```
@Entity()
export class Product {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number

 @Column()
 username: string;

 @Column()
 password: string;

 @Column()
 email: string;
```

try to look at the typeorm documentation for some reference:
https://typeorm.io/