# How to get tenant id from JWT on a muti-tenant NestJS+Passport implementation?

Tags: jwt, passport.js, nestjs, multi-tenant

I am extending the @Nurikabe answer to [NestJS Request Scoped Multitenancy for Multiple Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583231/nestjs-request-scoped-multitenancy-for-multiple-databases) to get the tenant ID from JWT.

This is the key problem: since I am using passport.js, and it resolves the jwt **after** the connectionFactory running in the module implementation, I don't have the tenant ID in that moment.

Does anybody know how to work it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with this kludge:

```js
function getTenantIdFromToken(token: string): string {
  var {acc} = jwt.decode(token) as Payload;
  return acc
}
```

in the connectionFactory:

```js
...
const tenant = getTenantIdFromToken(req.req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1])
...
```